# Picking spare inner tube size

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, innertube

My daily rider is a Schwinn MTB with 26" wheels/tires. Specifically the tire size is 26x47/52. On the inner tube there's a label that reads 26 x 1.90-2.125.

I'd like to purchase a few spare tubes in order to avoid getting stranded. *Question*: are 26 x **1.90**-2.125 and 26 x **1.95**-2.125 inner tubes interchangeable?

Comment: I would strongly doubt that the fabrication tolerances for bicycle inner tubes are better than 2.5%. That would mean that these sizes are not only interchangeable but effectively the same.

Comment: Presumably the "47/52" means 47-52mm tire width, depending on who's measuring.  This would be 1.85-2.05 inches.  This does kind of put you on the edge, but tubes are quite tolerant of size differences, and the 1.90-2.125 tube should be fine.

Comment: I've happily used a 1.25" tube in a 2" tyre, and an 18-25mm tube in a 32mm road tyre.  There's a lot of stretch in a tube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of inner tube, difference between 1.90 and 1.95 is totally negligible. The tubes will be completely interchangeable.

Rather than carrying a few spare tubes on your bike at all times, experienced riders most often carry only one spare tube + patch kit. It takes less space and weighs less than multiple spare tubes. It's rare to catch more than 1 flat on a single ride, and if you do, patching a tube takes only a few minutes.

Comment: I've been known to carry 4 spares, and need 3 of them, but that was before belted tires.  But if you use the bike to commute it's not a bad idea to keep a spare tube and a patch kit at work, as well as the set at home.

Comment: Many times you can use a smaller tube with a tire that is larger than the max number on the tube in a pinch. It's not always a great idea, but I do know some people who prefer to use 26in tubes on 29in tires so they don't have to buy different tubes and they can save a bit of weight.